# Density of Lipschitz functions in Bochner space with bounded support

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, gn.general-topology, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be separable and reflexive Banach spaces with Schauder bases.  Let $\mu$ be a non-zero finite Borel measure on $X$ and let $L^p(X,Y;\mu)$ denote the (Boehner) space of strongly p-integrable functions from X to Y.

Let $\operatorname{Lip}_c(X,Y)$ denote the set of Lipschitz functions from $X$ to $Y$ with *closed and bounded support*.

---

If $1 \le p< \infty$ then is $\operatorname{Lip}_c(X,Y)$ dense in $L^p(X,Y;\mu)$?

---

If not, then what if we additionally assume that X and Y are Hilbert spaces?

Comment: I think it is true without separability assumptions on $X$ and $Y$. It is sufficient to approximate a function $v\chi_S$ for $v\in Y$ and $S$ Borel measurable in $X$, so one is reduced to the scalar case. For $S$ open it is OK via distance function. From open to Borel it follows e.g. via the standard monotone class argument

Comment: @PietroMajer Could I ask for more details as an answer?